# ¿Cómo implementar correctamente mi función llamada "errorCallback" en AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Este es mi **controller**, lo que quiero hacer es que si no encuentra el archivo **.json** solicitado, que me redirija al template **'/error404'** pero no se por qué la función llamada **errorCallback** no me dirige al template **'/error404'**, les agradecería mucho si pueden ayudarme.

```js
.controller('articleCtrl', ['$scope','$routeParams','$http','$location',
  function($scope,$routeParams,$http,$location){
    $http.get('/json/articles/' + $routeParams.id + '.json').then(function successCallback(response){
      $scope.item = response.data;
    },function errorCallback(response){
      $location.path('/error404');
    });
  }]);
```

Comment: intenta usando..  `$window.location.href = '/error404';`

Comment: @rnd Saludos, gracias por comentar. Ya lo eh intentado y tampoco funciona.

Comment: Y si utilizas $location.path("#/error404")? Recuerda que debes registrar la ruta en tu app.js.

Comment: Saludos, gracias por responder. Claro, también tengo el **html5Mode** activado.

Answer (score 0):

intenta usando la funcion $apply

```js
.controller('articleCtrl', ['$scope','$routeParams','$http','$location',
  function($scope,$routeParams,$http,$location){
    $http.get('/json/articles/' + $routeParams.id + '.json').then(function successCallback(response){
      $scope.item = response.data;
    },function errorCallback(response){
       $scope.$apply(function() {
         $location.path('/error404');
         console.log($location.path());
       });          
    });
  }]);
```

Comment: Saludos, gracias por responder. No se que sucede tampoco utilizando la función **$apply** que me enseñaste funciona, ni siquiera aparece en la consola del navegador los datos del método **console.log();**

Comment: probablemente la función no esta generando un error podrias hacer el console.log(response.data) en la funcion suscces